# block spam containining link to http://6url.ru/ on windows 7 microsoft outlook pc

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

we receive alot of spam which is always from a new (spoof) address but contains a link in the body of the email which is always similar. the link always starts http://6url.ru/  and then has some random number/letters for the specific page. Is there a way to configure my email client to reject any email which contains any link starting in that way. I also have Norton 360 running so maybe that could be used to block the email, but if so I can't see that option. thanks if you can help

Comment: home user PC or company?  add **127.0.0.1  6url.ru/**  to the windows hosts file.  Run your own DNS server configure it to not respond to that address.

Comment: In general, I have found that filters incorporating Bayesian filtering are the most effective. I, personally, used [SpamBayes](http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/) on all of my work Outlook clients since I found it back in Outlook 2000. However, it doesn't play well with 64 bit versions.  Try looking at the options offered at [Gizmo's Freeware](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-spam-filter-for-experienced-users.htm) as a good starting place for additional filtration.

Answer (score -1):

i was getting a bunch of these as well and was able to set up a filter using the built in filter settings of Eudora 6.2.4 for Mac OS X. ive never really used Outlook but doesnt it have any filter options. in Eudora: for header select "body", for contains enter "6url.ru" and for action select transfer to trash. now they go direct to trash which is set to be emptied at quit. good luck

Comment: The question is about Outlook 2010, your answer is about Eudora. Please edit your post so it answers the question.